# Should sample masses of various samples undergoing Thermogravimetric analysis (TGA) be same?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I want to analyze the thermal degradation phenomena for 3 different samples using TGA. One of these samples comprises Polymer only, while the other two are loaded with two different percentages of fillers. Should the test weight of all three samples be the same prior to TGA, or degradation trends would hold regardless of differences in the three sample weights?

Comment: As long as the weight limits are within the manufacturer's specs I don't think there is a problem. The y-axis of TGA is % weight loss, so it takes original weight into account.

Comment: @AChem, what if the TGA results are to be compared to gauge if the addition of fillers has fortified the resistance to thermal degradation of the polymer these are added to in various percentages? If it takes original weight into account, then should not all weights match? For instance, if we have 3 samples (2 filler and one polymer-only), should not all three starting sample weights be the same?